# Apply sklearn trained model on a dataframe with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I trained a random forest algorithm with Python and would like to apply it on a big dataset with PySpark.

I first loaded the trained sklearn RF model (with joblib), loaded my data that contains the features into a Spark dataframe and then I add a column with the predictions, with a user-defined function like that:

```
def predictClass(features):
    return rf.predict(features)
udfFunction = udf(predictClass, StringType())
new_dataframe = dataframe.withColumn('prediction', 
udfFunction('features'))
```

It takes so much time to run though, is there a more efficient way to do the same thing? (without using Spark ML)

Comment: If I do the same thing with a Pandas DataFrame it is done in 2 seconds with something like predictions = rf.predict(data['features'])

Comment: Is it a scikit-learn's RF or Spark's MLLib RF?

Comment: It is a scikit-learn RF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do same thing in recent project. The bad thing about applying udf for each row that pyspark has to read sklearn model each time so that's why it takes ages to finish. The best solution I have found was to use .mapPartitions or foreachPartition method on rdd, really good explanation is here

https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/pyspark-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/map-partitions/README.md

It works fast because it ensures you that there is no shuffling and for each partition pyspark has to read the model and predict only once. So, the flow would be:

- convert DF to RDD
- broadcast model to nodes so it will be accessible for workers
- write an udf function which takes interator (which contains all rows within a partition) as an argument
- iterate through rows and create a proper matrix with your features (order matters)
- call .predict only once
- return predictions
- transform rdd to df if needed

Comment: Hello, @Jacek Can you give a example?

Comment: how should the return looks ?

Answer (score 1):

sklearn RF model can be quite large when being pickled. It is possible that frequent picklings/unpicklings of the model during task dispatch cause the problem. You could consider using broadcast variables.

From the [official document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables):

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner. Spark also attempts to distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can also use `pandas_udf` introduced in spark 2.3 to achieve high processing speed and distributed computation. It is based on `pyarrow` a python implementation of  *Apache Arrow* use for in-memory computation.

Comment: do you have an example notebook for this?

Comment: Hello @EmmaStin I came to know about `pandas_udf` that time but haven't implemented, I'm sharing few references that might help you :-) 
https://towardsdatascience.com/scalable-python-code-with-pandas-udfs-a-data-science-application-dd515a628896
https://kontext.tech/column/spark/370/improve-pyspark-performance-using-pandas-udf-with-apache-arrow

Comment: that's great @EmmaStin, could you please share the implementation?